# Licensed component not playing well with DI design

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

We've licensed some third-party e-mail components and have developed a set of components for our system that uses them. These components are then loaded dynamically at runtime by an IoC container.

However we have recently noticed in testing on a non-development machine that because the main .EXE which is "hosting" our components does not reference nor include a .licx for the third-party e-mail components (separation of concerns and all that) that it is causing the license check of the third-party e-mail components to fail.

Is there anyway around this?

It seems to be a pretty big flaw in the whole LicenseManager, .licx etc story of .NET?

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to include it in your project, there is no other way. Because Licx files actually creates an embedded resource in the same app.

Answer (score 0):

License files are just like configuration files - you can make libraries which reference them, but ultimately there is an artifact which has to live on disk with the executable.

I assume you have a .licx file and just don't want to reference it in any way from the application project. You can avoid that by including the .licx file in the installer - it ends up on disk in the right place and the application project is none the wiser.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation into the LicenseManager, it seems that the Validate method only scans the calling assembly of the current app domain (license information is stored as an embedded resource with a ".licenses" extension).

One solution is to run the code in a separate app domain. This way, the LicenseManager within the third-party component scans only the current assembly's embedded resources i.e.

```
    string assemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    AppDomainSetup appSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
    appSetup.ApplicationBase = new FileInfo(assemblyPath).DirectoryName;
    var newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewDomain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, appSetup);
    var myClassInstance = (MyClass)newDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyPath, typeof(MyClass).FullName);
    myClassInstance.myMethod("foo");
```

To make this work as you'll also need to inherit "MyClass" (plus any classes that pass between the two AppDomains) from MarshalByRefObject.